# Remove the tag from link

Tags: javascript

[image: display]

[image: console log]

I want to remove the tag(e.g. <p> <h1>) and leave only link

At first, I thought of cutting by detecting the tag <p>, but I think there will be a non-tag <p> case I don't know how to do that.

sorry for my English skill.

Comment: What is the "non-tag <p>" case you're referring to? Can you provide an example of each of the cases you're wanting to cover by this link extractor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to identify HTML tags in the input string. Replacing the identified HTML tag with null. This will result remove any queries with `<> and </>` and anything inside of the `<` `>` tags.

Here's an example of this below:

```js
function removeTags(str) {
    if ((str===null) || (str==='')) return false;
    else str = str.toString();
    return str.replace( /(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');
}
removeTags('<p>youtu.be/TJR10xK</p>');
```

Then log the input with `console.log(removeTags('<p>youtu.be/TJR10xK</p>'))`, what ever you want to do afterwards.

Comment: Thanks!, Im already solved my problem in the same way as your solution.